# É possível acessar multiplos bancos de dados em um mesmo projeto de Laravel 5?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel

O cenário é o seguinte: eu tenho um site web que pode ser acessado por 5 países diferentes -> `br.meusite.com`, `us.meusite.com`, `fr.meusite.com`, ... .

Todas as URLs direcionam para a mesma pasta dentro do servidor -> `www/meusite`.

Cada país tem sua basede dados: `br_bancodd`, `us_bancodd`, `fr_bancodd`, ... .

Em resumo, cada país tem seu banco de dados, mas todos os países compartilham os mesmos arquivos da pasta raíz `www/meusite`.

Quando o usuário acessa `www.br.meusite.com`, as transações serão efetuadas na base de dados `brbancodd`, eassim por diante. cada país com seu banco.

Atualmete o sistema está em funcionamento e para realizar essa tarefa de direcionamento usamos `rewrite rules` com `url amigaveis` para recuperar a URL que requisitou o acesso. Então recuperamos somente os 2 primeiros caracteres da URL que no caso será `br` ou `us` ou `fr`, ...  e a partir daí temos um arquivo `config.ini` que guarda as informações de acesso ao banco de dados para cada país, tais como `DB_CONNECTION(mysql),DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD`, entre outros,e seta o ambiente para realizaras transações com o banco de dado pertinente, até o usuário acabar a sessão.

Estou tentando pasar esse projeto para o laravel e estou com dificuldades nesse processo de recuperar os dois primeiros caracteres e direcionar para a database respectiva.

E como, no laravel 5,  as credenciais de acesso ao banco de dados  devem ser gravados em `.env` ou `config/database.php`, fico sem entender como gravar mais informações das diferentes banco de dados nesse cenário, pois só cabe informações de um único banco de dados, ou no máximo 2 (um em .env e outro em config/database.php).

Com certeza deve haver alguma maneira de permitir acesso a muitos bancos de dados em laravel 5. Alguém tem aguma idéia?

Comment: No caso essa conexão: $tabUser = DB::connection('us')->table('usertable')->get();
return $tabUser; seria chamada onde? nas models??

Answer (score 2):

Achei a solução. Vou postar aqui, caso interesse ao pessoal.

1. Abra o arquivo **.env** e apague as linhas abaixo:

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=br_bancodd
   DB_USERNAME=root
   DB_PASSWORD=
   ```
2. Abra o arquivo config/database.php e ponha as credencias de cada banco de dados. Se precisar pode repetir a array para quantos bancos de dados forem necessários na sua aplicação. Ex:

   ```
   'br' => [
           'driver' => 'mysql',
           'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
           'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'br_bancodd'),
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
           'charset' => 'utf8',
           'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
           'prefix' => '',
           'strict' => false,
           'engine' => null,
       ],
   'us' => [
           'driver' => 'mysql',
           'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
           'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'us_bancodd'),
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
           'charset' => 'utf8',
           'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
           'prefix' => '',
           'strict' => false,
           'engine' => null,
       ],
    ...
   ```
3. Chame seu banco de dados com o nome da conexão:

   ```
   $tabUser = DB::connection('us')->table('usertable')->get();
   return $tabUser;
   ```
4. Está pronto. Só precisa setar a conexão deafult para evitar escrever o nome do banco de dados todo o tempo da **sessão**.

   `DB::stDefaultConnection('us');`
5. Agora a requisição dispensa o nome do banco de dados:

   ```
   $tabUser = DB::table('usertable')->get();
   ```

Comment: well, se fez downvote.... comente ! Para mim funcionou, já que nunguém respondeu a dúvida.